# Autologon Desktop on Ubuntu 18.04 after exchange of disk that is mounted on /home

Tags: server, permissions, mount, login, fstab

I've got a Server running on that some user has got an low rights user that ist automated doing its login, so the users are able to use all the allowed functions.

Now the drive has got problems and one part at the end is broken. It is one of the big files that are not more needed and it is a raid that is there broken.

So I get all the data on a new drive and I did copy all with copying any user itself to the new substitution drive. The copy did not tell any faults and I thought everything is fine but when I do now change the entries in fstab, so that this drive is mounted on /home , I am able do login with password as another operator is able but the automated lowlevel user is not more starting automated and I could even watch, that after login in the user gets kickt out very soon after a short while and I have no idea what is wrong in this case.

Is there anything that I should know about or that I must preserv for this or change?

I did copy the data wich cp -a /home/user /newhome/ and the copy seems proper after I did remove the file that is in the area on the broken part of this drives. But I do want to change the drives out after it and don't want to develop all new for the main users with low level, as I don't want to train them all a new thing.

If I mount the nehhome with fstab on /home it isn't working proper but I am able to login with my own account and the major operator as well only the automated one low level User isn't logged in automated and gets kicked out after a short while.

I do really not know what I've made wrong.

Comment: Did you make sure that all the hidden directories and files (those startingwith a dot) was copied too ?

Comment: That was my first thought. But why should than my own user work, where the settings are as well in files starting with a dot.  two of 3 users work proper and it is only the user that is been automated logged on that doesn't works.

I did try inbetween now shopt -s dotglob ; cp -a /home/user /newhome/ will check the wrights soon. but need to call in the system for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be an ownership problem, try fixing it with the following commands.

Changing ownership of the home where username is your "lowlevel" account:

```
sudo chown username:username /newhome
```

Tell the system the home for the account has changed:

```
sudo usermod -m -d /newhome username
```

Also give the right permissions to the home:

```
sudo chmod 755 /newhome
```

Comment: Thanks for asking that again the last was it. I don't know when the mod of home changed to 555 and I am not able to understand why a cp -a isn't preserving all. But now it works.